# Where can I find documentation on the /_api/web/features/add SharePoint API?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We need to add a feature to a site collection dynamically at runtime.

I found [this](https://community.nintex.com/thread/5454) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109378/activate-a-site-feature-using-rest-api), but no official documentation.

It would be good to have some docs where we can investigate this approach further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "official" page is here (_api/web/features/add):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245237.aspx

But its not too useful. Very lacking in examples.

The feature collection (_api/web/features): 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246446.aspx